# Importing modules in derived python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm get an ImportError based on which file I call the modules from. Here's the directory tree:

```
my_package/
     --base.py
     --derived.py
     --run1.py
run2.py
```

Note that run1.py is inside the my_package folder, while run2.py is outside the my_package folder.

```
# base.py
  class Base:
    ...
```

To avoid the ImportError in run1.py, I need the following import statement in derived.py:

```
# derived.py
from base import Base
class Derived(Base):
   ...
```

To avoid the ImportError in run2.py, I need the following import statement in derived.py:

```
# derived.py
from . import base
class Derived(base.Base):
   ...
```

Is there a way to import the Base class into the Derived class and have it work from both run1.py and run2.py?

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Comment: change into it `from .base import Base` and in run2.py  `from my_package.base import Base`

Comment: @AdamStrauss, what you said works when running run2.py but not run1.py. Is there a "universal" import statement that would work when referencing the modules from any location in directory tree?